# Update left property while dragging

Tags: jquery

I want to update the `left` property of a `ul` while dragging, but it just jumps to -1980 as soon as I start dragging.

```
$('#draggable').on('drag', function() {

    var start = 0;
    var end = 2000;

    while (start <= end) {
        $('ul').css('left', -start);
        start+=20;
    }

});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EKp2H/)

Comment: Is #draggable the actual ul element or no?

Comment: no, #draggable is a div, ul has no direct relation to it.

Comment: can you simulate on jsbin.com

Comment: yes, I'll post it now on fiddle. Give me a few mins.

Comment: It could be because you are using `.css()` and not specifying the units. jQuery might handle that silently though. You could try using `.offset()` though instead, which doesn't require units.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the problem according to me is in loop

```
  while (start <= end) {
        $('ul').css('left', -start);
        start+=20;
    }
```

the loop ends when `start==2000` that's why you are getting left=2000 directly.

I don't know what you are trying to do. but if you want that each 20px left change to visible then try using the grid.

For horizontal scroller try this:

[Scroll Demo](http://jsbin.com/etenej/2/)

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#scroll').draggable({grid:[1,0]});
  $('#scroll').on('drag',function(event,ui){
    $('#text').css('margin-left',-ui.position.left);
  });  
});
```

Comment: Sorry, misread your answer at first. I agree. I think he should remove the loop entirely, and move `start` outside the scope of the anonymous function to preserve it's value across drag events.

Comment: i think he is trying to built an horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: I did it by multiplying the css left property by 3 each time.

Comment: Oh. i wasted my time :P . anyway good luck. and accept the answer to mark this as solved. otherwise other users will also try to solve it :P .

Answer (score 0):

Declare `start` variable outside of your `drag` handler:

```
var start = 0;
$('#draggable').on('drag', function() {   

    var end = 2000;

    while (start <= end) {
        $('ul').css('left', -start);
        start+=20;
    }

});
```

Comment: You need to wrap this in a closure to not pollute the global scope.

Comment: no, don't declare it as a _global_, declare it in the _enclosing scope_

Comment: enclosing scope means?@Alnitak sorry can u tell me what is enclosing scope

Comment: It does the same thing, just jumps to -1980 straight away